# Rails Minitest undefined method `greater_than_or_equal_to' for #<Shoulda::Matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, shoulda

I want to use ShouldaMatchers gem inside of Minitest to check simple model validation:

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  validates :share_ratio, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 100 }
end
```

To do so I've got a Minitest:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PortfolioTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context 'validations' do
    should validate_numericality_of(:share_ratio).greater_than_or_equal_to(0)
    should validate_numericality_of(:share_ratio).is_less_than_or_equal_to(100)
  end
end
```

But I'm getting an error:

> class:PortfolioTest': undefined method `greater_than_or_equal_to' for #Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::ValidateNumericalityOfMatcher:0x00007fba91da3ce0 (NoMethodError)

```
#Gemfile:
  gem 'shoulda', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 4.0'
```

I tried to change validation inside of the model:

```
validates_numericality_of :share_ratio, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 100
```

But error is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got one of them right, but not the other.

```
should validate_numericality_of(:share_ratio).is_greater_than_or_equal_to(0)
should validate_numericality_of(:share_ratio).is_less_than_or_equal_to(100)
```